# Druid count differ when we run same query on daliy and row data

Tags: druid

When  run query to ABS Data Source in Druid.I got some count but that differ when same query run with ABS_DAILY data source. And we make ABS_DAILY from ABS.

```
{
  "queryType" : "groupBy",
  "dataSource" : "ABS",
  "granularity" : "all",
  "intervals" : [  "2018-07-12T00:00:00.000Z/2018-07-13T00:00:00.000Z" ],
  "descending" : "false",
  "aggregations" : [ {
    "type" : "count",
    "name" : "COUNT",
    "fieldName" : "COUNT"
  } ],
  "postAggregations" : [ ],

  "dimensions" : [ "event_id" ]
}
```

Below json used for submit Daily  job for druid   which will create segments for  ABS_DALIY for specific time

```
{
  "spec": {
    "ioConfig": {
      "firehose": {
        "dataSource": "ABS",                                   
        "interval": "2018-07-12T00:00:00.000Z/2018-07-13T00:00:00.000Z",
        "metrics": null,
        "dimensions": null,
        "type": "ingestSegment"
      },
      "type": "index"
    },
    "dataSchema": {
      "granularitySpec": {
        "queryGranularity": "day",
        "intervals": [
          "2018-07-12T00:00:00.000Z/2018-07-13T00:00:00.000Z"           
        ],
        "segmentGranularity": "day",
        "type": "uniform"
      },
      "dataSource": "ABS_DAILY",                            
      "metricsSpec": [],
      "parser": {
        "parseSpec": {
          "timestampSpec": {
            "column": "server_timestamp",
            "format": "dd MMMM, yyyy (HH:mm:ss)"
          },
          "dimensionsSpec": {
            "dimensionExclusions": [
              "server_timestamp"
            ],
            "dimensions": []
          },
          "format": "json"
        },
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  },
  "type": "index"
}
```

I quired to ABS_DAILY  with below  it return different result than ABS Count. Which it should not.

```
{
  "queryType" : "groupBy",
  "dataSource" : "ERS_DAILY",
  "granularity" : "all",
  "intervals" : [ "2018-07-12T00:00:00.000Z/2018-07-13T00:00:00.000Z" ],
  "descending" : "false",
  "aggregations" : [ {
    "type" : "count",
    "name" : "COUNT",
    "fieldName" : "COUNT"
  } ],
  "postAggregations" : [ ],

  "dimensions" : [ "event_id" ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are counting rows of daily aggregates.

To summarize pre-aggregated counts you now need to sum the count column (see `type`)

```
{
  "queryType" : "groupBy",
  "dataSource" : "ERS_DAILY",
  "granularity" : "all",
  "intervals" : [ "2018-07-12T00:00:00.000Z/2018-07-13T00:00:00.000Z" ],
  "descending" : "false",
  "aggregations" : [ {
    "type" : "longSum",
    "name" : "COUNT",
    "fieldName" : "COUNT"
  } ],
  "postAggregations" : [ ],

  "dimensions" : [ "event_id" ]
}
```

Comment: is it not possible to fire count query for Daily ? I don't have any metrics , Still we want to count record for daily , How is possible to achieve ?

Comment: Right, an issue is that with `"queryGranularity": "day"` you are asking for a daily rollup, so events with the same set of columns value (here its all columns as dimensions is left empty) will be merged into daily buckets, hence reducing the count of events stored, the original count is lost unless you add a count metric when creating the daily segments. There is also the fact that Druid stores time in milisec so will automatically merge events in the same millisec unless rollup is off